# How to retrieve Outlook Tasks using Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, outlook-restapi

Friends,

I'm trying to retrieving Outlook Tasks and it throwing "No usable default class 'exchangelib.folders.Tasks' folders. I'm using 2.7 python version.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to get Outlook task. Like this "POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/tasks"

For more information, please see

[Outlook Task REST API](http://simonjaeger.com/outlook-task-rest-api-get-organized/)

[Outlook Task REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/task-rest-operations#GetTasks)